# NodeJS wrapper for Dynamo and Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

Is there a simple abstraction layer that supports both DynamoDB and MongoDB, failing that a simple wrapper on top of [Dynamoose](https://dynamoosejs.com/) and [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/).

I've tried building the wrapper myself but can't seem to work out how to accomplish this, I was hoping to do something along the lines of this, unfortunately it just ends up being undefined when I try to import it.

```
import dynamoose from 'dynamoose'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const name = 'MyModel'
const schema = {
  id: String
}

const isAWS = () => {
  return true
}

export default isAWS() ? dynamoose.model(name, schema) : mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

If needs be I could try writing a wrapper myself using typescript that just abstracts the basic CRUD functions.

Comment: Node ootb does not support import/export, do you an additional tool for that (babel for ex)? Just want to rule that out...

Comment: I'm using babel with jest, I was also using vanilla js with require() but still having similar issues

Comment: Have you figured out a solution to this?